# displaying email body as html in c# textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am imitating my email client on a asp page.  I have a gridview that displays things like from,subject,attachments, and the body.  The body is html.  When I view it in the grid view and set htmlencode= 'false' i can see it correctly.  However, I want to the display it inside a textbox, so it can edit and forward it or reply.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: You will not be able to edit HTML within a normal textbox as a WYSIWYG editor... you'd need something like [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

Comment: Or http://www.freetextbox.com/

Comment: I like Telerik's RadEditor (not free)

Comment: Does the ReachTextBox haven't auto parsing for html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the HTML into a rich text editor to enable to user to edit it - be aware that most rich text editors out there are not designed to create *email safe* HTML and they will require a substantial amount of tweaking if you are going to support more than the most basic formatting.

Some example rich text editors:

- http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/
- http://www.freetextbox.com/

Answer (score 0):

Look into using a WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get) text editor like [Cute Editor](http://cutesoft.net/ASP.NET+WYSIWYG+Editor/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use an **HTML Editor / TextBox**, we use DevExpress components, very high quality but not free, there are also alternatives like Telerik or Infragistics and also free alternatives... see here: [Best Free available wysiwyg html editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964725/best-free-available-wysiwyg-html-editor)

Answer (score 0):

[Try this...](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/57176/Parsing-HTML-Tags-in-C)
You can-t display html in textbox but you can get the source code.I am using this:) [click here](http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/994.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try dinamycly add html code to page:

```
<div runat="server" id="myDiv">
</div>
```

and then set its InnerHtml property from the code-behind:

```
myDiv.InnerHtml = "your html here";
```

but with this way you cannot edit it...

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Devexpress Controls,

you can use ASPxHTMLEditor.

It works exactly as your requirement is.